# C# listening on microphone

Tags: c#, microphone

HI,

Is it possible to listen on the microphone in C# (.NET) and do something when volume goes to some point? We have Avaya desk phone at work and I'd welcome if I could see when it rings on the monitor.. Would like to do a practical tool to monitor for that ring sound with microphone glued to the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this forum thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/52312bbc-5fa2-491a-b3bd-aa7267fc2a8c